# Kernel and image of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Not sure about this one. Here's my work for it:

**Problem Statement:** Determine the dimensions of the kernel and the image of the linear operator $T$ on the space $R^n$ defined by $T(x_1,...,x_n)^t=(x_1+x_n,x_2+x_{n-1},...,x_n+x_1)^t.$

**My attempt:** The dimension of the kernel is the number of vectors in the basis for $[0,0,...,0]^t$, or $0$, because the dimension is 0. The dimension of the image = 1, because by the dimension formula, $\dim(image(T))=\dim(V)-\dim(\ker T)=1-0=1.$

This seems too easy to be true. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: For $n>1$, you can see that $T(1,0,...,0,-1)^T = 0$, so the kernel is not trivial.

Comment: The vector $(1,0,...,0,-1)$ lies in the null space, hence the dimension cannot be zero. The kernel is the set of vectors $\ker T = \{ x | T x = 0 \}$. The comment above shows that $\dim \ker T >0 $ whenever $n >1$. Treat $n=1$ separately. Also $\dim V = \dim \mathbb{R}^n = n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**case 1**:Let $n=5$(odd)

$T(x_1,...,x_5)^t=(x_1+x_5,x_2+x_4,x_3+x_3,x_4+x_2,x_5+x_1)^t.$

We know that,standard basis for $R^5$ is {(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)}

$T(1,0,0,0,0))^t=(1,0,0,0,1)^t.$

$T(0,1,0,0,0))^t=(0,1,0,1,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,1,0,0))^t=(0,0,2,0,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,0,1,0))^t=(0,1,0,1,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,0,0,1))^t=(1,0,0,0,1)^t.$

So we get

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\
       0 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

This can be reduced to Echelon form as

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\
       0 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$

So $dim(image(T))=3$

$dim(V)=5$

Using $dim(V)=dim(image(T))+dim(ker T)$

$dim(ker T)=2$

**case 2**:Let $n=6$(even)

$T(x_1,...,x_6)^t=(x_1+x_6,x_2+x_5,x_3+x_4,x_4+x_3,x_5+x_2,x_6+x_1)^t.$

$T(1,0,0,0,0,0))^t=(1,0,0,0,0,1)^t.$

$T(0,1,0,0,0,0))^t=(0,1,0,0,1,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,1,0,0,0))^t=(0,0,1,1,0,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,0,1,0,0))^t=(0,0,1,1,0,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,0,0,1,0))^t=(0,1,0,0,1,0)^t.$

$T(0,0,0,0,0,1))^t=(1,0,0,0,0,1)^t.$

So we get

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0& 1\\
       0 & 1 & 0   & 0& 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0   & 0& 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0& 1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

This can be reduced to row echelon form as

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\
       0 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$

So $dim(image(T))=3$

$dim(V)=6$

Using $dim(V)=dim(image(T))+dim(ker T)$

$dim(ker T)=3$

**Conclusion** $dim(ker T)=\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $dim(image T)=\frac{n+1}{2}$,if $ n$is odd

$dim(ker T)=\frac{n}{2}$ and $dim(imageT)=\frac{n}{2}$ ,if $ n$is even

Comment: Is it intended that the Row-Echelon form for both 5 and 6 are identical?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $e_k$ be the vector of zeroes with one in the $k$th position.

If $n=1$, then $Tx= 2x$.

If $n >1$,
then it is easy to see that $T e_k = e_k+e_{n-k+1}$, and so $T e_k = Te_{n-k+1}$. In particular, the range is given by ${\cal R}T = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_k+e_{n-k+1}\}_{k=1,...,\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}.$

Comment: So, because the matrix A of T w.r.t. T(e_i) is I_n, dim(image T)= n/2?

Comment: No. That is not the matrix of $T$. Try it for $n=3$, and the matrix will be very obvious. Also, the formula above shows that $\dim {\cal R} T = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. That is the largest integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Ok. How did you get the largest integer less than or equal to n/2?

Comment: Well, for even $n$ the there are $\frac{n}{2}$ distinct  $e_k + e_{n-k-1}$ terms, for $n$ odd, there are $\frac{n-1}{2}$ distinct terms. The formula $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ is a shorter way of writing this.

Comment: Actually, for n odd, aren't there (n+1)/2 distinct terms, thus making it the ceiling of n/2?

Comment: @copper.hat, OP is right: When $n$ odd then there $\frac{n+1}{2}$ distinct terms.

Comment: @Silent: Thanks for catching that. If $n$ is odd there are ${n+1 \over 2}$ points, if $n$ is even, there are ${n  \over 2}$ terms, so a common formula would be $\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor $.

Comment: My second last comment is wrong.